# Simple Json ClassNotFoundException when executing JAR built by gradle

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea, javafx

I recently developed a simple JavaFX Game which used Simple Json. The dependency has been defined in Gradle dependencies and the **game runs fine with Gradle run** command. But when I create a jar file using - **Gradle Jar and run** it the following **error** shows up:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.json.simple.parser.ParseException
```

[image]

Here is the picture of my build.gradle file:

[image]

How do i Fix this?

Comment: I had the same problem. I added the jar manually and it worked for me. Try adding it manually.

Comment: How do I add Jar manually?

Comment: In the build path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the default package behavior. The package phase of tools such as Gradle and Maven only copy the application sources (Java classes and resources from src directory), and NOT include files from dependencies.

Therefore the jar file produced by default does not have dependency classes or resources.

There are many solutions to run a java program from the jar file with dependencies:

1. Place the app jar as well as dependency jars in a directory (lib) and add it to the classpath when running the main class.

```sh
java -cp lib/*.jar  com.game.MainClass
```

2. Create a fat (uber) jar. Gradle plugins like [Shadow](https://github.com/johnrengelman/shadow) can generate a single jar with all dependencies packed in it. Just specify the main class in Manifest.

```sh
java -jar myAppFat.jar
```

3. Use plugins like [Launch4J](https://github.com/TheBoegl/gradle-launch4j) to generate Windows executables. This is great if you want to ship simple "click to run" apps to users.